# What causes this extreme difference in lightning quality?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, light

Image of problem: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1620825/extreme-lightning-difference-in-same-scene.html

This is what happens in my game (see image)...

I don't know what is causing it. When the player (a bouncing ball) is in this area the linerenderer often doesn't work and some of the pins dissapear to then randomly appear again.

The lightning is set to baked and there are 2 directional lights in the scene. The second scene (which you see on the image) is activated (set active) later in the game. Could this problem be caused because the level isn't baked?

If you have other solution, please share them! :)

-Regards Quint van O.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com may be abetter fit for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reload or open a scene while **editor** is in play mode, Unity not bake the lightning. That's why you see darker light on opened scene.

It only occurs in the editor. It will not produced when you build your game.

To see how your game behave in editor you can bake the lightning for each scene. Go to Window -> Lighting -> Settings -> On the bottom untick **Auto Generate** and then click **Generate Lightning**